# Java Support Download Data from Url more then `Int.MAX_VALUE` (Url.openConnection())

Tags: java, url, download, inputstream

I'm confused when I want to download more than `Int.MAX_VALUE` content size.

`UrlConnection.contentLength` it return `Int` so if it is Bigger. it may return -1

```
//i'm reading 1024 * 4 at a time
Long offset = 0 //download data
Long size = UrlConnection.contentLengthLong
```

and if i use `UrlConnection.contentLengthLong` so question arises that, when i read `UrlConnection.getInputStream.read(byte[] dest, Int offset, Int length)` and my `Long offset` reach at `Int.MAX_VALUE` so that i can't convert `Long offset` to `Int`. it possible `Int Overflow`.

so what is the alternative way to read more than `Int.MAX_VALUE` from stream because `Long` value not supported in `.read(byte[] dest, Int offset, Int length)` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximal size of an array in Java cannot exceed the integer range. To read more data from a stream you have to do it piece by piece. You will never have to use long parameters for offset or length when doing that.

Comment: But bro, when i downloded data Int.max_size, so instad of I need to put Long value  
  on it (Like - `read(byte4ksize, offset (Long) , lenght)`)   lenght variable is next 4k byte after download 4k data

Comment: offset is an offset in the array (which cannot be larger than MAX_VALUE) not in the stream.

Comment: sure, check the docu: `off - the start offset in array b at which the data is written.`